# Android Device Chooser doesn't list emulators with older APIs than the build version

Tags: android, android-emulator

My application is built on 2.2, but it is backwards compatible down to 1.6.  I've used reflection for the newer methods.

When I try to run it on an emulator in Eclipse, it only lists my 2.2 AVDs.  I need to test on 1.6 to ensure compatibility.

I've tried building with Android 2.2 and with Google APIs 2.2 with no luck. (what's the difference, anyway?)

I have set `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4"  targetSDK="8"/>` in my manifest. I also tried `targetSDK="4"`.

Thanks.

Comment: It is `android:targetSdkVersion`, not `targetSDK`. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open AVD manager, start 1.6 emulator. Run project in eclipse - started 1.6 emulator will be in the list.

Comment: That does it. Then you don't need to worry about ever building it in any API other than 8, which is required for app to SD.

Answer (score 0):

You can't build to a 1.6 emulator when your app is built on 2.2.  You can however, do the opposite.  Build your project on 1.6 and as long as you set android:minSdkVersion you can build to all emulators higher than that version.

1. Right click on your project in the Package Explorer.
2. Select Properties.
3. Select Android.
4. Under Project Build target select API 4 (1.6).
5. Hit OK.

Now when you build your project it can build on a 1.6 emulator assuming you have one setup.

Comment: That works, except I have to take out the line for app2SD 'android:installLocation="auto"'  I suppose it's safe to just add this one line back in and change Build Target back to API 8 right before I release the app?

Comment: @TenFour04: Older devices should ignore your `android:installLocation` attribute.

Comment: That's true, but if I follow the above steps, the compiler gives an error on that line. I think that's why the developer site says to change build target to 8 if you want to enable this feature.